GitHub actions environment variables are not loaded in Vite build
This morning I really struggled to get a React deployment working with GitHub Pages because the variables defined in the workflow were not being loaded in the application. As a consequence, the page was not being loaded under the right base name.
This was my configuration:
.github/workflows/static.yml
# ...

env:
  VITE_REPO_NAME: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}
  VITE_SERVER_URL='https://this-is-a-server-url.com'
  
jobs:
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v5
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
        with:
          path: './dist'
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v4

vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig, transformWithEsbuild } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? process.env.REPO_NAME || '/'
    : '/',
  envDir: 'environment',
})

I looked through many resources, but the closest I could find were these questions:
GitHub actions not recognizing environment secrets [duplicate] and How to access environment secrets from a Github workflow?
However, the proposed solutions didn't work for me or seemed more complicate than I thought they should be

You should set env inside Build Job. For example:
- name: Build
    run: npm run build
    env: 
      MY_SECRET_1: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET_1 }}
      MY_SECRET_2: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET_2 }}
      MY_SECRET_3: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET_3 }}


I solved it. As I explained, the variables were not reaching the execution of the aplication. Then, I added them to the .env.production file.
.github/workflows/static.yml
# ...
# Removed the env variables from here
  
jobs:
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Save environment variables
        # Save the variables into the .env.production file
        run:
          echo "VITE_REPO_NAME=${{ github.event.repository.name }}" >> environment/.env.production &&
          echo "VITE_SERVER_URL=https://this-is-a-server-url.com" >> environment/.env.production
      - name: Test environment variables
        # Test if the variables were being stored
        run:
          cat environment/.env.production
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v5
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
        with:
          path: './dist'
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v4

vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig, transformWithEsbuild, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  // Load the current env file (production in build case) located in the environment directory
  const env = loadEnv(mode, 'environment');

  return {
    // ...
    // NODE_ENV is located in the process variables
    base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    // VITE_REPO_NAME is in the env loaded 
      ? env.VITE_REPO_NAME || '/'
      : '/',
    envDir: 'environment',
  }
})

And as an extra, as I were using react-router, I added the basename to the options:
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
  // ...
], {
  basename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    // Vite dispose the variables of the environment from import.meta.env
    ? `/${import.meta.env.VITE_REPO_NAME}/`
    : '/',
})


Is it .env.production or production.env? In the description, you've mentioned production.env but in the workflow .env.production is being used. You might want to update it your answer to make it consistent.

Thanks for the correction, it is .env.production.
